# Macro expansion and stringification: How to get the macro name (not its value) stringified using another macro?

Tags: c, macros

Out of interest:

```
#define _ACD 5, 5, 5, 30

#define DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS   _ACD 

#define DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY { DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS }
```

Using DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS macro only, how to get _ACD stringified in a const unsigned char [].

```
const uint8 startMsg[] = ?? DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS ;
```

Will result **_ACD** only.

What will be the correct macro expansion for getting _ACD here.
In context of [How to stringify macro having array as #define a_macro {5,7,7,97}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689825/how-to-stringify-macro-having-array-as-define-a-macro-5-7-7-97)

Comment: I think it is not possible. But I know nothing is impossible. Anyone ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(The standard disclaimer about not abusing the C preprocessor without a really good reason applies here.)

It's certainly possible to do what you want to do.  You need a `STRINGIFY` macro and a bit of macro indirection.

Typically, `STRINGIFY` is defined with one level of indirection, to allow the C preprocessor to expand its arguments before they undergo stringification.  One implementation is:

```
/* The # operator converts symbol 'v' into a string */
#define STRINGIFY0(v) #v
#define STRINGIFY(v) STRINGIFY0(v)
```

However, you'll find that this isn't enough:

```
#define _ACD 5, 5, 5, 30
#define DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS   _ACD 
#define DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY { DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS }

#define START_MSG STRINGIFY(DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS)
const char startMsg[] = START_MSG;
```

Here, `STRINGIFY(DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS)` expands to `STRINGIFY0(5,5,5,30)`, and the C preprocessor complains that you've given `STRINGIFY0` too many arguments.

The solution is to delay the expansion of `_ACD` so it only expands to `5,5,5,30` when you want it to.  To do this, define it as a function-like macro:

```
#define _ACD() 5, 5, 5, 30
```

This way, `_ACD` will only be expanded when you "call" it: `_ACD()`.  `DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS` will now expand to `_ACD`, and you have to expand it further by "calling" it: `DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS()`.

The following code illustrates the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY0(v) #v
#define STRINGIFY(v) STRINGIFY0(v)

#define _ACD() 5, 5, 5, 30
#define DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS   _ACD 
#define DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY { DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS() }

#define START_MSG STRINGIFY(DEFAULT_NETWORK_TOKEN_KEY_CLASS)

const char startMsg[] = START_MSG;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("%s\n",startMsg);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Outputs the **_ADC**. I learnt a lot today. THANKs