# Is there a way of passing macro names as arguments to nested macros without them being expanded when the outermost macro is expanded?

Tags: c++, c, macros

(Apologies for the long title, but I couldn't think of a less specific one which would be clear enough)

I need to pass the name of an (object-like) macro to a nested (function-like) macro, as in the following (trivial) example:

```
#define ROOT_FUNC(INPUT) int v_ ## INPUT = INPUT
#define CALLER_FUNC(INPUT) ROOT_FUNC(INPUT)

#define INTA 1
#define INTB 2
#define INTC 3
```

Now, if I write `ROOT_FUNC(INTA);` in my code I get an integer variable called `v_INTA` with the value `1`. If I define a variable in code, `int INTD = 4;`, and then write `CALLER_FUNC(INTD);` I end up with an integer variable called `v_INTD` with the value `4`.

But if I write `CALLER_FUNC(INTA);` I get an integer variable called `v_1` with a value of `1`, because `INTA` is expanded to `1` at the time `CALLER_FUNC` is expanded, before `ROOT_FUNC` is expanded (i.e. `ROOT_FUNC(1)` is what gets expanded).

If I change line 2 to: `#define CALLER_FUNC(INPUT) ROOT_FUNC(#INPUT)` (i.e. stringifying `INPUT`), a compiler error occurs because it is being asked to define an integer variable called `v_"1"` (an invalid name) and give it the value `"1"` (a non-integer value).

I know the preprocessor is fairly primitive, but is there any way of achieving what I'm after?

(Second edit for further clarification, I want `CALLER_FUNC(INTA);` to expand first to `ROOT_FUNC(INTA);`, then to `int v_INTA = 1;` – i.e. I want `INTA` to be expanded inside `ROOT_FUNC`, rather than outside it. I am looking for an answer in principle, not just any way to change `CALLER_FUNC` to produce the result `int v_INTA = 1;`, which would be trivial).

---

P.S.
In case you are wondering, I originally had a use case involving signal handling (e.g. taking macro names like `SIGINT` as inputs for nested macros), but got around these limitations by simplifying my structure and abandoning nested macros; hence this question is purely academic.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want. Please show an example of what the expected output is.

Comment: What's `MASTER`? Did you mean `ROOT_FUNC`?

Comment: @remyabel The desired output would be: `CALLER_FUNC(INTA);` expanding to `ROOT_FUNC(INTA);`, then to `int v_INTA = 1;` (the spefic example is just a random and trivial one). At the moment it expands to `ROOT_FUNC(1);` and then to `int v_1 = 1;` (i.e. INTA is expanded before it is passed to ROOT_FUNC(), whereas I would like it to happen after).

Comment: @T.C. I did indeed – have changed.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If I'm reading the spec correctly, arguments are macro-expanded before they are substituted into the replacement list, except when they are the operand of a `#` or `##`, but in those cases you'd have no way to get the argument back.

Comment: @remyabel That would give the desired output in this specific example (as would just `#define CALLER_FUNC(INPUT) int v_ ## INPUT = INPUT`), but it is not really addressing what the question is asking: `CALLER_FUNC(INTA);` gets expanded to `int v_INTA = EXPAND(1);` and then to `int v_INTA = 1;` rather than going through `EXPAND(INTA);` – INTA is still expanded with the outermost macro.

Comment: What are you seeking if the `#define CALLER_FUNC(x) int v_ ## x = x` does not do what you are after?  It gives the desired output as requested in the question/comments.  You can define `#define VAR_NAME(x) v_ ## x` so that you can subsequently do things like `int z = VAR_NAME(INTA) + VAR_NAME(INTB);` and get the right variables mentioned.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the question was more about what is mechanically possible with the precompiler rather than how to produce a specific result in a trivial example. Macros are just shorthand so by definition any specific example offered to illustrate the problem could be solved by simply going through the code and manually expanding them (as you have done here) – the question is about whether it is possible to choose the layer at which a macro gets expanded when it is passed as an argument to a nested function macro ... and the answer is probably no.

Comment: Correct: the answer is No.  The C preprocessor is fairly primitive in many ways, and you don't have control over when macros are expanded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Macro expansion and stringification: How to get the macro name (not its value) stringified using another macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693219/macro-expansion-and-stringification-how-to-get-the-macro-name-not-its-value-s)

Answer (score 6):

If you can expand the first macro to take two arguments, you could get it to work like this:

```
#define FUNC(intname, intv) int v##intname = intv
#define CALL_FUNC(intv) FUNC(_##intv, intv)

#define INT1 1
#define INT2 2

int main(void)
{
  int INTD = 4;

  CALL_FUNC(INT1);
  CALL_FUNC(INT2);
  CALL_FUNC(INTD);
}
```

The output (from GCC), looks something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int INTD = 4;

  int v_INT1 = 1;
  int v_INT2 = 2;
  int v_INTD = INTD; // not sure if you want the value of INTD here - I guess it doesn't matter?
}
```

Which I guess is what you are after - if I read your question right?

The token pasting prevents the preprocessor from expanding it out and simply generates a new token which is passed to the second macro (which then simply pastes that together to form the variable), the value (which is expanded) is passed down as the second argument..

---

**EDIT1**: Reading more through what you are after, I'm guessing the above trick is not what you reall want...ah well..

Comment: This is actually a very good hack – indeed, this would have worked in my original (now abandoned) use case. This of course applies only to the subset of cases where an inner function wants to paste the macro, but there are only three possible cases: the inner function can paste, expand or stringify the macro, and with the latter two it is irrelevant where in the chain the macro is expanded/stringified, the result is always the same. Hence, I think we now have a complete model. The only downside is that multiple caller functions might have to contain the same paste, lessening macro efficiency.