# Stringifying a macro expansion that is another macro

Tags: c

I am wondering if there is anyway to stringify a macro expanision that is another macro before it gets completley expanded.  Easier to show in code:

```
#define A_MACRO 0
#define ANOTHER_MACRO A_MACRO
```

I want to expand `ANOTHER_MACRO` into the string `"A_MACRO"`

Double stringification does not work, it stringifies `ANOTHER_MACRO` into `0`. I have searched and cannot find an answer and played around with macros in a test application, but I have had no luck. Is it possible?

Edit: I do not have the ability to change either macro.  A_MACRO has a descriptive name that I would like to use, and we "point" to it with another macro that follows a standard name and I can grab it with a file parser.  I was hoping I could just write a stringification macro to get that name, but I think I will have to find a way to latch onto it with my file parser, thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: `#define ANOTHER_MACRO "A_MACRO"` ? Explain why it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you mean you want some macro `F` defined such that `F(ANOTHER_MACRO)` will be replaced by `"A_MACRO"`?

Comment: start with `#undef A_MACRO`

Comment: @Eugene, the macro's are defined in another file that is automatically generated.  A_MACRO would be a non-standard description.  I am parsing the file and finding the ANOTHER_MACRO macro that follows a standard description that I can grab onto

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You can either not expand the macro argument, or you can fully expand it.

There may be a solution to whatever the underlying problem is, but this is a dead end.

Comment: That's what it feels like, thanks.

Comment: @tyler_30130: if you explain the real problem, someone might be able to help you find a solution. But don't do that in a comment. Post a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11694231/11683?

Comment: @gserg: if you can alter the definition of the macro being expanded, there are lots of possibilities. Using a function-like macro might be a way of restructuring the problem. But if the macro definitions are a given (eg. they are in an external header which cannot be modified) then sime other solution is necessary.